# Cardinalties of Reals and Naturals

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

How can I show  $n^{\aleph_0} = \mathfrak c$, if $n$ is finite and at least $2$?
               Also how can I show  $\aleph_0 ^{\aleph_0} = \mathfrak c?$

I know there is a theorem thats says $2^{\aleph_0} = \mathfrak c$, from this I said
 $\mathfrak c = 2^{\aleph_0} \leq n^{\aleph_0}$ because $n$ can be $2$ or $>2$. So $2^{\aleph_0}\leq n^{\aleph_0}$. But how can $n^{\aleph_0}= \mathfrak c$? Isnt $\mathfrak c \leq n^{\aleph_0}$.

Note: This a not a homework question. Its a practice problem. Getting help is allowed.

Comment: It's because $n^{\aleph_0}\leq (2^n)^{\aleph_0}=2^{n\cdot\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}$. So you have $2^{\aleph_0}\leq {n^\aleph_0}\leq 2^{\aleph_0}$ and Cantor–Bernstein–Schroeder gives you that they are equal.

Comment: sorry how did you get n^ℵ0 ≤(2^n)^ℵ0. Whats the reasoning behind that?

Comment: Since $n\le 2^n$, then there are at least as many sequences of points of a set with $n$ elements as there are sequences of points of a set with $2^n$ elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that $n^{\aleph_0}$ is the cardinality of all the functions from a set of cardinality $\aleph_0$ into a set of cardinality $n$.

For every $n$ consider the set $\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$ and take $\Bbb N$ as a set of cardinality $\aleph_0$. So $n^{\aleph_0}$ is the cardinality of $\{0,\ldots,n-1\}^\Bbb N$.

Obviously, if $2\leq n$ then $\{0,1\}^\Bbb N\subseteq\{0,\ldots,n-1\}^\Bbb N\subseteq\Bbb{N^N}$. Therefore $2^{\aleph_0}\leq n^{\aleph_0}\leq\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$.

To show equality we first note that $\left(A^B\right)^C\sim A^{B\times C}$, and therefore $\left(2^{\aleph_0}\right)^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0\cdot\aleph_0}$. Since we know that $\aleph_0\cdot\aleph_0=\aleph_0$ it follows that it is equal $2^{\aleph_0}$. Now we have, $$2^{\aleph_0}\leq\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}\leq\left(2^{\aleph_0}\right)^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}.$$

Comment: Again how do we show aleph_0*alpeh_0 = aleph_0. I can show n*aleph_0 = aleph_0. Are they the same?

Comment: Ahmed, you can find a bijection from $\Bbb{N\times N}$ to $\Bbb N$.

Comment: I figured thanks

Comment: I kept on thinking about this problem ℵ0^ℵ0 <= (2^ℵ0)^ℵ0.

Comment: And what did you think about it? This is one of the basic laws of cardinal exponentiation: $$\kappa<\lambda\implies\kappa^\mu\leq\lambda^\mu.$$